# field update using trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a trigger on ContentDocument object when a file is uploaded in notes & attachment i have to update a field "uploaded on"  in communication object with value of latest uploaded date but i am receieving error in line no. 8 System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

code:

```
trigger contentTrigger on ContentDocument (After insert) {
    List<Customer_Communication__c> customerList = new List<Customer_Communication__c>();
    Set<Id> custIds = new Set<Id>();
    List<Customer_Communication__c> custListToUdpdate = new List<Customer_Communication__c>();    
    for(ContentDocument attach : trigger.New){
        //Check if added attachment is related to customer communication  or not
        if(attach.ParentId.getSobjectType() == Customer_Communication__c.id.SobjectType){
            custIds.add(attach.ParentId);
        }
    }
    customerList = [select id, Uploaded_on__c from Customer_Communication__c where id in : custIds];
        for(Customer_Communication__c acc : customerList){
            Customer_Communication__c commuToUpdate = new Customer_Communication__c();
            commuToUpdate.Id=acc.Id;
            commuToUpdate.Uploaded_on__c=system.today();
            system.debug('----------->>>>>>uploaded'+commuToUpdate.Uploaded_on__c);
            custListToUdpdate.add(commuToUpdate);
        }
        update custListToUdpdate;
}
```

can anyone assist me in this ?

Comment: `ParentId` is the containing library, not the object to which the document is attached. Your trigger probably needs to be on `ContentDocumentLink`.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Please [edit] your post to call out which specific line in your code is throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `SObjectType` with the null safe operator. The same line also has another error.

**Incorrect**

```
if(attach.ParentId.getSobjectType() == Customer_Communication__c.id.SobjectType){
```

**Correct**

```
if(attach.ParentId?.getSObjectType() == Customer_Communication__c.sObjectType){
```